# IJCADのブロック内のエンティティ色を変更しても更新されない

Tags: ijcad, arx

いつもお世話になっています。IJCAD 2018でARX（GRX）を使って開発をしています。

ブロック内にあるエンティティの色を変更する処理を入れたのですが、Windows 7では変更後の色が反映されるのに、Windows 10では変更されません。

なぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

これ、私も同じ経験があるのですが、色を変更した後にacedRedrawを呼び出せば解決します。

AutoCAD 2018でも同様の現象が発生しましたが、同じ方法でクリアしました。